# Python script not returning any results while web scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am looking to scrape a list of URLs -- I want to visit each one & then return all IMG links contained within each HREF on the page (in essence, visit each link and return the image address of the player headshot on each player profile).

I have a successful script for one set of URLs below - this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1TD4YmhfAsnSL_Fwo1lckEbnUVBQB6VyKC05ieJ7PKCw')
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)
# AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
# worksheet.insert_row(AddValue, 3)


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")

        div_profile_box = soup_player.find('div', {'class': 'profile-box'})

        img_tag = div_profile_box.find('img')
        image_url = img_tag['src']

        row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url, "Image URL": image_url}

        data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2021',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2020',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2019',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2018',
]


res = []
for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)
    res = [*res, *data]

if res != []:
    header = list(res[0].keys())
    values = [
        header, *[[e[k] if e.get(k) else "" for k in header] for e in res]]
    worksheet.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

This returns an output of: Player Name, Player URL, Player Headshot:

[image: correct output]

I tweaked the code to tweak for a different set of URLs, but it's not returning any information.  No errors are showing, but nothing seems to be happening:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1TD4YmhfAsnSL_Fwo1lckEbnUVBQB6VyKC05ieJ7PKCw')
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")

        div_profile_box = soup_player.find('div', {'class': 'profile-box'})

        img_tags = div_profile_box.find_all('img')
        for i, img_tag in enumerate(img_tags):
            image_url = img_tag['src']
            row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url,
                   f"Image URL {i}": image_url}
            data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [
    "https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc",
    "https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/minutes/All/desc/2",
    "https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/minutes/All/desc/3"
]

for url in urls:
    data = get_links(url)
    for row in data:
        worksheet.insert_row(list(row.values()))
```

I also checked a version debugging "soup_player", but I'm still not receiving any results:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1TD4YmhfAsnSL_Fwo1lckEbnUVBQB6VyKC05ieJ7PKCw')
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        print(f"soup_player for {name}: {soup_player}")

        div_profile_box = soup_player.find('div', {'class': 'profile-box'})

        img_tags = div_profile_box.find_all('img')
        for i, img_tag in enumerate(img_tags):
            image_url = img_tag['src']
            row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url, f"Image URL {i}": image_url}
            data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [    "https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc",    "https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/minutes/All/desc/2",    "https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/minutes/All/desc/3"]

for url in urls:
    data = get_links(url)
    for row in data:
        worksheet.insert_row(list(row.values()))
```

Any advice as to what I may be doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you done debug prints of `soup_player` to see whether you're actually reading anything?

Comment: @TimRoberts thank Tim, I added in what I had tried, but I wasn't getting any results for that - I'm not reading anything but not understanding why based off the site

Comment: "I'm not reading anything" -- Where?  Have you printed `req.url.content` to make sure you can read those URLs at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.*

---

Main issue is that your selection of initial table elements will not find any, so `ResultSet` is empty.

Change:

```
for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
```

to:

```
for td in soup.select('td:has(>a[href^="/player"])'):
```

Comment: I ran into a separate issue, but going to try to diagnose first - seems to be looping through the same URL

Comment: Definitely, this is due to the loop that is supposed to extract the different images, which is why the URL of the profile appears several times.

Comment: thank you very much - it takes me a little bit to figure these things out, so going to spend some time on it. hoping i can solve this one myself!